# Checking patterns using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to check patterns in a string using regex.
My requirements are

1. The string should always start with `%` or (
2. Immediately After `%` there should be a number and vice versa any number should be preceded by `%` always
3. the string can only contain following characters and word `%` `(` `)` `and` `or` numeric value

`Valid string (%1 and %2 or %3)`

`Invalid %%1`

I tried the following

```
regex ^[%(]+[%0-9]+[(]
```

Please help

Comment: Looks like whitespace characters are OK too, right?

Comment: Yes whitespace characters are ok

Comment: Try regex ^[%(]+[%0-9\s]+[)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^(?:\(|%[0-9]+)(?:\s+|%[0-9]+|and|or|\(|\))*$
```

Starts with an opening bracket or a percent then a series of numbers, then goes on to allow spaces or a percent followed by a series of numbers any number of times.  If you give a more specific example of what you are trying to match I can be more specific

[image]

This does not force matching brackets.  You need a recursive js function for that

EDIT

Alright, here is a more specific function to account for spacing and numbers around seperators

```
^(?:\(|%[0-9])(?:\sand\s|\sor\s|\(+)(?:(?:%[0-9]|\)+)(?:\s(?:and|or)\s(?:%[0-9]|(?:\(\s?)+))?)*\s?\)*$
```

This will match something like this: %3 and %4 or ( %2 or %3 )
but fails when you try it on: %3 and %4or ( %2 or %3 )
note the missing space between the %4 and the or

Again, brackets dont need to be closed so it matches: %3 and %4 or ( %2 or %3
and it also matches: %3 and %4 or ( %2 or %3 ))))

it can deal with immediately nested brackets like this: %3 and %4 or ((%2 or %3) and %9 )

Im sure I have missed cases, let me know what issues your run into

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Is it possible to explain the regex?

Comment: Of course.  it has two parts each surrounded by (?: ).  The ?: means the parens will not capture, it makes the regex a little bit faster and is useful if all you need to do is check if the regex matches not pull what it matches out of a string.  inside the first brackets is \(|%[-9]+.  That matches either an opening bracket or a percent followed by one or more numbers.  The second portion \s+|%[0-9]+|and|or|\(|\) matches one or more spaces or a percent followed by one or more digits or 'and' or 'or' or either bracket 0 or more times.  Let me know if you want a specific explanation of something

Comment: Thanks a lot wolffer-east

Comment: Looking at Theox's answer below I forgot that you can combine the symbols into one or which would make the regex a bit smaller.  Changing that out would give you (?:[\s()]+|%[0-9]+|and|or)* for the second portion of the regex

Comment: @Rakesh KR, how did you generate that image?

Comment: @wolffer-east I wrote the following one ^(?:\(|%[0-9]+)(?:\s+|%[0-9]+|\) and+|\) or+|\)+|and|or|\()*$ which is taking care of the closing bracket thing I asked for. Let me know if anything looks wrong to you. AT the moment it seems to be working. I will write recursive function for taking care of the opening and closing brackets. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Be careful with that one,  looks like you may be missing some escapes on parenthesis, as well as parens around the 'and' and 'or'. ' and+' will match anddddd instead of ' and and'.  Also try to remeber to escape your spaces, that way it will match tabs as well.  This is a valid version of the one you just posted: ^(?:\(|%[0-9]+)(?:\s+|%[0-9]+|(?:\) and)+|(?:\) or)+|\)+|and|or|\()*$.  Take a look at my edit above, it is a bit more robust.  Also check out <http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex>, it is a page I use to test regex

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the white space from the string first just to make the regex easier.

This doesn't match exactly what you described, but matches what I think you're trying to do based on your example:

```
\(?%\d+\)?((and|or)\(?%\d+\)?)*
```

Note that it does not guarantee that the parentheses are all matched.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution :

```
^(%\d|\()(%\d|and|or|[\s()])*$
```

This will match strings beginning with "%N", followed by any combination of "and", "or", whitespaces, ( ), and % followed by a number.

Comment: Good call on combining the symbols.  I forgot that for a second there.  You are only missing the option to start the string with an opening paren

Comment: @wolffer-east : Indeed, i changed that. I also saw that my regex match strings like "%1 andandandandandorororor" which is probably unwanted. I'll edit my post when I find how to fix this.

Comment: yeah, we would have to split out the %\d (or in my case %[0-9]) from the rest.  Not sure if whitespace is required or not

Answer (score 0):

try this, perhaps can help :

```
^[%][0-9]+|^[(][%][0-9]+[)]
```

http://RegExr.com?37h10